# JS 'Unterminated string constant' error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

On my view I have this:

```
@if(ViewBag.Test == true)
{
    <script>
        window.alert("test")
    </script>
}
```

Here is a picture:

[image]

As you can see, the red wave-line is saying that it is an *Unterminated string constant*.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could be stupid. Try adding `;` at the end of the line?

Comment: @PraveenKumar just tried, did not resolve..

Comment: Can you post the full code so that there might be something else that's causing the issue?

Comment: Make sure your quotes are ASCII double quotes, not "curly quotes".

Comment: Tried that as well @Barmar... Nothing unusual. Check here: http://i.imgur.com/xE7WwFb.png

Comment: The problem is with the argument to `encodeURIComponent` in the image, not the code you posted in the question. The string has a newline in it, which isn't allowed.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Wait a second, you're not the OP. What does that image have to do with the question?

Comment: @Barmar I checked if there's any illegal invisible characters in the provided code. Generally they might escape the `"`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar You're assuming he copied the code accurately.

Comment: So the IDE thinks there's a problem, what about when it actually runs? does it work as expected?

Comment: @Rhumborl I don't think it would even compile?

Comment: @Rhumborl it does work fine, but in the *error list* it has a warning saying 'unterminated string constant'

Comment: @PraveenKumar I've had VS randomly go crazy before and not recognize anything as razor, but it runs fine.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Did you ever figure this out? I've a similar issue, code runs fine but the ide is giving out ..

Comment: @AidanO I believe that is a bug within VS.. I didn't do anything with it since it ran fine.

Answer (score 1):

It may be choking on the closing script tag.

Are you able to do something like the following:

```
string script = "<scr" + "ipt>window.alert('test');</scr" + "ipt>";
Response.Write(script);
```